# How to run electircal wire underground?

Tags: electrical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run a wire underground to an outdoor post lamp?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5517/how-do-i-run-a-wire-underground-to-an-outdoor-post-lamp)

I need to run power to an automatic gate operator at the entrance to my driveway. I have 2 questions:

1) What type of conduit do I need to use underground?

2) And how deep should I bury the line?

Comment: An electrician friend of mine, when helping me run a buried line, highly recommended using outdoor-rated Romex even in conduit because as he put it "It seems like no matter how carefully it was laid, buried conduit always leaks at some point."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need conduit rated for outdoor use. It's typically PVC, gray in color, and is UV rated (so it doesn't break down in sunlight)
2. check local electrical codes to be certain (though I think 18" is typical)

Comment: And you need to properly seal that underground PVC with the proper glue.

Comment: And UF cable too, I think.

Comment: which is better? metal or PVC for underground conduit? is metal even an option?

Comment: @roartechs If you're running the conduit under the lawn or other low load area, I would use PVC. If you are going under a driveway or other high load location, I would be afraid of the PVC collapsing so I would use metal.

Comment: I believe galvanized is an option (again, check local codes) but the challenge with metal is that it's more work to seal the connections. As Greebo points out, you do want to seal the PVC with PVC cement which is easy to do and makes a complete seal.